# WTF! How can a adware get installed inside system level folder on a non-rooted phone?

Tags: malware, system-apps

I dont know  how could this happen.The phone started popping ads randomly everywhere.I ran malwarebytes and found a RockClient.apk installed on my phone in the system level.There was another Dropper agent installed uninstalled it.But this was in systems so i disabled this for now.

I am curious how could this have occurred,did it replace my rom signature.Or is there a very genius guy behind it.Also is there a way to remove this without rooting the phone?(probably there isn't one).But still i am curious to see.Did this happen to anyone else?

[image: MalwareBytes Scan results]]
[image: /system/app]
[image: /system/app/.apk]

Comment: What kind of device is this? Some shady manufacturers install malicious apps on their devices that activate after a set amount of time. You can often reset this by doing either a factory reset or cleaning that app's data.

Comment: Is this a Micromax device? It comes pre-installed on many of them, it isn't really malware, more of adware as it will send targeted pop-ups and other advertising to you. It isn't harmful, just annoying... Since Micromax hasn't commented on it in over a year, it assumed it's on purpose and not just an error using an infected development kit or something like that.

Comment: I guess it came preinstalled with your device. Some OEMs like Micromax regularly do that. [Check this to know how to disable it](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/).